# AWS Pull latest code from codecommit on EC2 Instance startup

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

There seem to be lot of discussion around this topic however nothing precisely for my situation and hasn't resolved it for me so far.

I have my code placed in aws codecommit.

I have created an AMI for one of my running Ubuntu instance in AWS and created a launch configuration using this AMI along with an auto scaling group.

I want to base/modify my launch config AMI every month or so to ensure the AMI itself has recent updated code and so newly launched instances (thru auto scaling) can just pull latest changes from codecommit repo on launch - resulting in reduced launch time.

To achieve this, I placed below code in User data (cloud-init) script and selected a IAM role that has full permissions over all EC2 and codecommit as well as IAM:Passrole permission. However on launch, the script always throws error and does not pull changes (I intentionally kept a file in repo to test)

Option 1

```
#!/bin/bash
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
cd /path/to/my/folder/
git remote set-url origin https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/reponame
git pull origin master
```

It throws below error

```
Error
fatal: $HOME not set
fatal: $HOME not set
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com': No such device or address
```

Option 2 -

Tried this option as well with SSH (although haven't tried any further fixes for this)

```
#!/bin/bash
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
cd /path/to/my/folder/
git remote set-url origin ssh://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/reponame
git pull origin master
```

Got a different error -

```
Errpr: 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can someone please hep me understand where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Option 1, it looks like the home directory wasn't created yet. When you are setting the global git config, it will go into the home directory's .gitconfig file. Though the option doesn't need to be global, e.g. you can switch the order of the lines to:

`cd /path/to/my/folder/
git config credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config credential.UseHttpPath true`

This is provided that you have set up EC2 instance roles correctly and that your AWS CLI is able to get the EC2 instance role credentials from EC2 metadata to call AWS APIs.

Though its unclear from the output whether the AWS CLI is installed. The CLI needs to be installed for the git config lines you've posted to work because its going to call "aws codecommit credential-helper" to get a temporary username and password based on the instance role credentials.

In Option 2, you do not need to use the credential helper at all. I am sorry if that was not clear in the documentation. You do, however, need to upload a public key to IAM (instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html#setting-up-ssh-unixes-keys)

You will also need to figure out a way to distribute your public and private key pair to the EC2 instances that you are trying to scale up, this can be quite troublesome.

You can also generate static credentials for CodeCommit (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html#setting-up-gc-iam) and put them on your EC2 instance in something like a .netrc file.

IMO Option 1 seems the most secure since you don't have to deal with passing secrets around.

Comment: Thanks Yilun. For option 1, I can confirm CLI is installed on base AMI - below is the output of aws --version command - "aws-cli/1.11.138 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-85-generic botocore/1.6.5". -----

About the ec2 role I used to create instance, it has 2 managed policy, ec2fullaccess and codecommitfullaccess and 1 inline policy for iam:passrole to * resources.  just to clarify, this is the role which I choose on "configure instance" step while creating instance... is this right?   ----- what do you mean by "home directory not created yet"? Is it supposed to create a different home directory?

Comment: Hi Yilun, for option 2, the instructions are to set public key for IAM user and that's where I get confused. Since I created an IAM role (not user) and the role page does not have any section to upload public key. Does it mean I can upload the key to any other user who has access to codecommit? How does that user assume identity while instance boot up?

Comment: Hi Yilun, just a quick update. I followed details on this beautiful article and it resolved the issue.... something worth looking and probably adding to aws documentation. https://jameswing.net/aws/codecommit-with-ec2-role-credentials.html

Comment: I'm glad you got it resolved you can see that the guide you linked set system level config rather than global level config. I assume that this is because the home directory used in global git config is not created yet. Your home directory is /home/<username> usually.

Comment: In option 2, if you attach the SSH Public Key to an IAM user, that user will not be assuming the role at all, instead, when your EC2 instance presents the public key to CodeCommit, for the git pull/git clone operation, it will have the permissions that are associated with the attached IAM user, whatever they happen to be.